# Java direct download link

Tags: java

is there a direct download link to the JDKs and JREs? Maybe even a stable link to the latest JDK? I need to download Java at the command line and don't want to click through the Oracle homepage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linux JDK x64: http://cds.sun.com/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/CDS-CDS_Developer-Site/en_US/-/USD/VerifyItem-Start/jdk-6u23-linux-x64.bin?BundledLineItemUUID=E62J_hCyhPIAAAEtMZZKP.CW&OrderID=l1qJ_hCy3hQAAAEtI5ZKP.CW&ProductID=6gGJ_hCwIQYAAAEsKIMcKluK&FileName=/jdk-6u23-linux-x64.bin

Linux JDK: http://cds.sun.com/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/CDS-CDS_Developer-Site/en_US/-/USD/VerifyItem-Start/jdk-6u23-linux-i586-rpm.bin?BundledLineItemUUID=hXWJ_hCy95oAAAEtKIhKP.CX&OrderID=A2aJ_hCyVuMAAAEtGohKP.CX&ProductID=QhOJ_hCw.dUAAAEsFIMcKluK&FileName=/jdk-6u23-linux-i586-rpm.bin

Windows x64: http://cds.sun.com/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/CDS-CDS_Developer-Site/en_US/-/USD/VerifyItem-Start/jdk-6u23-windows-x64.exe?BundledLineItemUUID=DIiJ_hCyV5YAAAEtpHxKP.CY&OrderID=2eeJ_hCy7yAAAAEtmXxKP.CY&ProductID=ZUuJ_hCwEmwAAAEsOoMcKluK&FileName=/jdk-6u23-windows-x64.exe

Windows: http://cds.sun.com/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/CDS-CDS_Developer-Site/en_US/-/USD/VerifyItem-Start/jdk-6u23-windows-i586.exe?BundledLineItemUUID=uFmJ_hCy1vsAAAEtkyhKP.CY&OrderID=AReJ_hCys4MAAAEtiChKP.CY&ProductID=_omJ_hCwMp4AAAEsQIMcKluK&FileName=/jdk-6u23-windows-i586.exe

Comment: How did you find them?

Comment: I use Google for search)

Comment: Strange... I used the Oracle download page before, and all links to the JDKs had a session ID in them, so the download somewhere else was not possible. Now it seems to work. Thanks anyway.